# How to get out parameters working in SharePoint workflows

Tags: sharepoint, moss, workflow

I'm trying to create a custom workflow action with an output parameter for error handling. Working from various examples, I can't get Parameter Direction="Out" to work.  Everything seems right, but when I try to assign the output to the "error" variable in SharePoint Designer, it places asterisks around it and flags it as a workflow error.  Here is what the action XML looks like:

```
<Action Name="Create Folder"
  ClassName="ActivityLibrary.CreateFolderActivityTest"
  Assembly="ActivityLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx"
  AppliesTo="all"
  CreatesInList="ListId"
  Category="Custom">
  <RuleDesigner Sentence="Create a folder %1 in the %2 base folder. If an error occurs it will be output to %3.">
    <FieldBind Field="FolderName" Text="folder name" Id="1"  />
    <FieldBind Field="BaseFolderPath"  Text="folder path" Id="2"/>
    <FieldBind Field="OutError" DesignerType="ParameterNames" Text="out error" Id="3"/>
  </RuleDesigner>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="FolderName" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" />
    <Parameter Name="BaseFolderPath" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" />
    <Parameter Name="OutError" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="Out" />
  </Parameters>
</Action>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want Direction="InOut" from the looks of the binding

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the issue is with the parameters and not maybe the variable in SPD?  Certainly nothing looks wrong with your XML.

I always hated the way SPD and workflows make you create a variable within the workflow and another within the page to assign to the same value as the workflow variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get anywhere with this?  I suspect the problem was more likely in your logic code rather than this xml (.actions) file.  It looks perfectly acceptable to me.

Comment: Nope. Couldn't get it to work in the amount of time I had allocated to this approach, so had to move on. That's the problem, it looks perfectly acceptable, but doesn't work.